# Get LinkedIn Updates additional statistics

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I am using LinkedIn API to get company page updates and its statistics. I am able to get likes and comments count and other details for every update of a company by sending the following query to API

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/[companyid]/updates/key=UPDATE-c123456789?format=json
```

However, I also want Impressions, Clicks, Interactions for every update. I am not able to find any documentation on API about it. Please help !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing with LinkedIn is that their documentation is not explaining possibilities in details, only the general API endpoints. I was looking for profile update statistics and couldn't find it.
Long story short, you can write the endpoint like this:

```
/v1/companies/{company_id}/historical-status-update-statistics:(time,like-count,impression-count,click-count,engagement)?time-granularity=day&start-timestamp=1466899200000&format=json&update-key={update-key}
```

You can find in the [docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#historical_updates) more for this topic. The trick is the `(time,like-count,impression-count,click-count,engagement)` part. You must include **time-granularity** and **start-timestamp**. Make sure you set the timestamp in milliseconds (unix*1000). If you don't provide update-key, you will get statistics for many updates.Please let us know if you've found other solutions for this.

Comment: How did you figure these fields out? Is there a list with the possible fields anywhere? I discovered these additional fields by guessing: `comment-count,share-count`